# How to find count / index in a XSL FO table

Tags: xsl-fo

How to find the count / current index of a row/column in a XSL FO table?

Eg. the result of the following table should render

(a)
(b)
etc...

but instead the table renders (a) (a) ...

```
<fo:table>
   <fo:table-body>
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:call-template name="sectionColumn">
                  <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="position()"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
      <fo:table-row>
         <fo:table-cell>
            <fo:block>
               <xsl:call-template name="sectionColumn">
                  <xsl:with-param name="rowIndex" select="position()"/>
               </xsl:call-template>
            </fo:block>
         </fo:table-cell>
      </fo:table-row>
   </fo:table-body>
</fo:table>
```

Template

```
<xsl:template name="sectionColumn">
   <xsl:param name="rowIndex"/>

   <xsl:if test="$rowIndex != ''">
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="$rowIndex = '1'"><xsl:value-of select="'(a)'"/></xsl:when>
         <xsl:when test="$rowIndex = '2'"><xsl:value-of select="'(b)'"/></xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="'Could not resolve ' + $rowIndex"/>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `position()` is evaluated by the XSLT processor when it creates the XSL-FO output.  It returns the position of the current node in the current context. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-position.) Your sample code doesn't change the current node, so `position()` can't help but return the same number.  Numbering starts from '1', so you won't get a '0' from `position()` at all.  From what you show, you might as well insert the literal numbers.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @TonyGraham I am trying to call a template from each row by having the current row index as a parameter inside the template. The template then returns a certain result depending on the index parameter.

Comment: Please add a small sample of your input XML, the rest of the current template, and the expected output so that we can get a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: @TonyGraham please see my latest edit on this post above where an actual template is included.

Comment: The code you've shown so far doesn't make any reference to the input XML. position() refers to the node being processed in the input XML.